# Upgrading Central Machinery 9" Bandsaw

Tags: band-saw

I currently own a Central Machinery (Harbor Freight) 9" Benchtop Bandsaw. I would like to upgrade the cooling blocks on it but I am unsure which ones will fit. I tried searching for a central machinery 9" specific cooling block but came up with nothing.

The other thing I would like to somehow upgrade/modify is the table's miter slot. I want to install a rip fence or some type of adjustable guide for straight and angled cuts. I'm under the impression that the ones available for purchase generally fit a T-track. The slot on the bandsaw table is too small to fit anything made for T-tracks. Does anyone have any ideas on how to modify the table?

| Bandsaw Specs |  |
| --- | --- |
| Electrical Rating | 120V~ / 60Hz / 2.5A |
| Motor No Load Speed | 1725 RPM |
| Blade Speed | 2460 FPM |
| Throat Depth | 9″ |
| Table Pivot (Tilt) Capacity | 0~45° (Right Tilt Only) |
| Blade Size | 1/8″ – 1/2″ W x 0.01″ T x 62″ L |
| Miter Gauge | 0~60° Left & Right |
| Miter Slot | 5/8″ W x 1/4″ D |
| Base Mounting Holes | 4 x 3/8″ Diameter |

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Unfortunately your first query is a shopping question and those are off-topic for this SE I'm afraid. Also, you're asking separate things here; although they all relate to your bandsaw each specific query should ideally have its own Question, to more tightly focus the Answers and make the Q&A easier for future searchers to find and benefit from. So please edit this Q to be about the mitre slot only.

Comment: You don't mention it so just in case you haven't found out yet, one of the must-do upgrades for almost all bandsaws is to buy a third-party blade. Apparently the majority of stock blades are Not Good™, frankly can even be a bit crap (both in quality and their type/features). A good new blade can *completely* transform the way inexpensive saws work, according to new users. You might want to especially look at new blades if you want to cut tight curves (narrow blade) and do resawing (may be a wider blade, with a low tooth count). Also look at skip-tooth designs.

Comment: *"I want to install a rip fence"* Good news, this doesn't require a T-slot, in fact it's very typical that these clamp to the table using conventional clamps of some kind, and as it happens we have a recent Q&A that includes something on this, [Flottjetb bandsaw attachments](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/12953/flottjetb-bandsaw-attachments/12954#12954).

Comment: I would suggest that you pull the existing cooling blocks and measure them up with your calipers. Go shop for higher quality ones of the right size. Also, there are 100s, if not 1000s of videos on the Tube of You where people talk about updates/upgrades to their HF tools, go see what's there, someone has probably already done that and posted their video with all the info you need.

Comment: An internet search for "cooling blocks" gets me direct match, but brings up many links to Cool Blocks which are only a type of guide block. Is this the same thing?